# Почему classList.add не работает после clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

До того, как сработает clearInterval(), всё работает, но после прохождения цикла и очищения интервала, невозможно по новой добавить класс, чтобы замкнуть функцию на бесконечное выполнение. Почему так происходит и как это исправить???

```js
var block = document.querySelectorAll('li'); 
var intervalId;
var counter = 0;

intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter == block.length) {
        function f1(){
            block[0].classList.remove('active');            
            block[1].classList.remove('active');            
            block[2].classList.remove('active');           
            block[3].classList.remove('active');          
            block[4].classList.remove('active');            
            block[5].classList.remove('active');          
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
         f1();
     };

    block[counter].classList.toggle('active');
    counter++;


  
}, 300);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
}
  
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li.active {
      list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
        <li>Четвёртый</li>
        <li>Пятый</li>
        <li>Шестой</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: для бесконечного выполнения надо в какой-то момент обнулять `counter` - см. ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var block = document.querySelectorAll('#mylist > li'); 
var intervalId;
var counter = 0;

intervalId = setInterval(() => {

    if (counter === block.length) {
            block.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'));
            counter = 0;
     }else{
         block[counter].classList.toggle('active');
         counter++;
     }
}, 300);
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
}
  
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li.active {
      list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
    <ul id='mylist'>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
        <li>Четвёртый</li>
        <li>Пятый</li>
        <li>Шестой</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: else не обязательно на 10й строчке

Comment: block.forEach(b => b.classList.remove('active'));

А что такое b??? Никак не могу понять!

Comment: это аргумент функции, которая последовательно получает каждый элемент блока: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=js+foreach&oq=js+foreach&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1848j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: советую посмотреть следующие вещи: функции из array.prototype, object.prototype, библиотека lodash